# How to add new data to a TableView in addition to the previous data that it already contains?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, twitter

I am working with my Twitter app. I am fetching the search result in a TableView. When I am refreshing the search results, the table gets populated with the new incoming tweets and the earlier one goes out. Can any one suggest me a way to just add new tweets along with the earlier tweets?

```
//my array
-(NSMutableArray *)retrievedTweets
{
if (retrievedTweets == nil)
{
    retrievedTweets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];
}
return retrievedTweets;
}


-(BOOL)checkCanTweet
{
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
{
    self.goButton.enabled = YES;
    self.goButton.alpha = 1.0;
    return YES;
}
else
{
    self.goButton.enabled = NO;
    self.goButton.alpha = 0.6;
    return NO;
}
}

//search function

-(void)searchTweet{

if (retrievedTweets == nil) {
    retrievedTweets=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
//retrievedTweets = nil;

if ([self checkCanTweet])
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = 
    [accountStore
     accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter ];
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                            withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted)
         {
             NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

             if ([accountsArray count] >0)
             {
                 [self.retrievedTweets removeAllObjects];

                 NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q="];
                 //NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23"];


                 NSString *textString = searchBarText.text;
                 NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]init];

                 if(textString==nil)
                 {
                     self.goButton.enabled = NO;
                 }
                 else {

                     self.goButton.enabled = YES;

                     unichar  c = [textString characterAtIndex:0];

                     if(c == '#'){

                         NSString *newStr = [textString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [textString length]-1)];
                         urlString=[str1 stringByAppendingFormat:newStr];
                     }
                     else {

                         urlString = [str1 stringByAppendingFormat:searchBarText.text];
                     }
                 }



                 ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];
                 TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] parameters:nil
                                                           requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

                 [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                 [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                  {
                      if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200)
                      {
                          NSError *jsonParsingError;
                          NSDictionary *homeTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

                          NSDictionary *results=[homeTimeline objectForKey:@"results"];
                          Search *current;


                          for (NSDictionary *dict in results)
                          {


                              current = [[Search alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
                              [self.retrievedTweets addObject:current];
                          }

                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


                              [self.tableViewPost reloadData];

                          });
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i\n", [urlResponse statusCode]]);
                      }
                      //   [self.tableViewPost reloadData];
                  }];
             }
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Error, Twitter account access not granted.");
         }
     }];
}

[searchBarText resignFirstResponder];
```

}

Comment: can you add some code, how you are saving your new data?

Comment: I think you got only 50 tweets. Am i correct?

Comment: no, I am getting 15 (default) tweets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not given the tableview delegates code.You need to addobject to the NSMutableArray everytime you retrieve the new data from web service.Before hitting the web service get the tableview's array(mutable) that you are using and add objects to it from the web service after parsing.Assign this array to the tableview array and then reload table.

Comment: Agreed. the way I would do it is used [table reloadData] and the delegate methods will update your table from your array.